# Class with single call to an api resource

Tags: php, class, oop, laravel, dependency-injection

I have a class, that has a method call to an api resource, and other methods that use the api call method output. As it is right now, every time some other method calls the api method, the api method makes a request to the api over and over again. What would be the best way to make a single call to the api and then use the output trough my class? See example.

```
class foo {

    $param1;
    $param2;

    function getApi {

        return 'call_to_api' . $this->param1 . $this->$param2;
    }

    function do_stuff_1 {

        return 'do_some_other_stuff . '$this->getApi() . $param1
    }

    function do_stuff_2 {

        return 'do_some_other_other_stuff . '$this->getApi() . $param2
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not obvious what you want to acheive, do the various methods call the external api with different parameters? Or is the result from the external api the same for each method? If the latter, simply save the result of the api call to a private class variable, and use that in other methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Laravel Cache](http://laravel.com/docs/cache) in your requests to the API:

```
$url = 'http://api.url.com?data1=x&data2=y';

if (Cache::has($url)) 
{
    $apiResult = Cache::get($url);
}
else
{
    $apiResult = $this->apiGetResult($url);

    Cache::put($url, $apiResult, 5); // cache for 5 minutes
}

return $apiResult;
```

So, your API will only be hit if the it was never hit before or if the cache expired. The nice thing of using Laravel cache is that it works between requests, so if your application needs that same data in the next request it will not hit the API again.

Answer (score 0):

You can create sort of a cache by calling the API again only if the parameters have been modified:

```
  class foo {

    $param1;
    $param2;
    private $resultAPI = '';
    private $paramModified = false;

    function getApi {
      if ($this->resultAPI == '' || $this->paramModified) {
        $this->resultAPI = 'call_to_api' . $this->param1 . $this->$param2;
        $this->paramModified = false; 
      } 
      return $this->resultAPI;
    }

    function setParamX($val) {
      if ($this->paramX != $val) {
        $this->paramX = $val;
        $this->paramModified = true;
      }
    }

    function do_stuff_1 {

        return 'do_some_other_stuff . '$this->resultAPI . $param1
    }

    function do_stuff_2 {

        return 'do_some_other_other_stuff . '$this->resultAPI . $param2
    }
  }
```